# How can I have a MouseUp EventTrigger only trigger on right button click in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

The title says it all:

How can I have an EventTrigger only trigger on certain conditions, e.g. how can I have a MouseUp EventTrigger only trigger on right button click, by means of using XAML only?

Comment: You can't. EventTrigger is not a conditional trigger. As the name implies, it triggers on an event. But you can handle a more specialized event instead for example MouseRightButtonUp event.

Comment: Thank you for enlightening me! My question rather was a hypothetical one: Will it be able to filter on EventTrigger. You answered it perfectly well. – Would you want to add your comment here as an answer? I would be happy to upvote then.